# ¿Qué son los "Handlers" en C#?

Tags: c#

Amigos, me encuentro con esa palabra *"Handlers"* (manejador en español). Para qué se usan o qué relacion tienen con lo delegados? Si alguien me pudiera orientar acerca de que temas leer relacionados con los Handles o algunos ejemplos, los agredeceria.

Comment: Para entender los handlers necesitas tener una idea clara de los delegados: https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/delegates/index lectura recomendada

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Handlers

Un *"Handler"* es un método controlador de eventos en el receptor de eventos, es decir, el que se ejecuta en el momento de que el receptor es notificado de que ha ocurrido un evento. Para esto, se debe relacionar el método con el evento que va a controlar cuando ocurra.

> **En la [página](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/events/) oficial del sitio de Microsoft MSDN tenemos el
>   siguiente ejemplo:**
>
> En el ejemplo siguiente se muestra un método de control de eventos
>   denominado `c_ThresholdReached` que coincide con la signatura del
>   delegado EventHandler. El método se suscribe al
>   evento `ThresholdReached`.
>
> ```
> class Program
> {
>     static void Main(string[] args)
>     {
>         Counter c = new Counter();
>         c.ThresholdReached += c_ThresholdReached;
>
>         // provide remaining implementation for the class
>     }
>
>     static void c_ThresholdReached(object sender, EventArgs e)
>     {
>         Console.WriteLine("The threshold was reached.");
>     }
> }
> ```

### Delegados

Los delegados son simplemente variables que almacenan una referencia a una función que retorne el mismo tipo de variable que es el delegado, es decir, son variables que apuntan a una función que retorna el mismo tipo de variable.

Si tu delegado es tipo `void`, únicamente podrá referenciar a funciones de tipo `void`.

Para declarar un delegado de hace uso de la palabra clave delegate en (C#) y Delegate (en Visual Basic).

> **En la [página](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/dotnet/standard/events/) oficial del sitio de Microsoft MSDN tenemos el
>   siguiente ejemplo:**
>
> En el ejemplo siguiente se muestra cómo declarar un delegado denominado `ThresholdReachedEventHandler`:
>
> ```
> public delegate void ThresholdReachedEventHandler(object sender, ThresholdReachedEventArgs e);
> ```

En esta [respuesta de Stack Overflow en español](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1650/qu%C3%A9-son-los-delegados-en-c) responden más específicamente acerca de qué son los delegados en .net?