# Qué elementos se pueden delegar y a qué elementos se les puede delegar?

Tags: c#, poo

Hola cómo están todos? estoy estudiando la utilización de los delegados en c#, pero tengo unas dudas acerca de:

1. A qué elementos se les puede delegar?
2. Qué se puede delegar?

No estoy entendiendo a qué se refiere, si alguien puede ayudarme le agradecería muchísimo, Saludos

Comment: un delegado es una propiedad/variable que apunta a un metodo (normalmente un evento), asi tu puedes cambiar la funcionalidad cambiando al metodo que quieres apuntar

Comment: Yo creo que esta pregunta está relacionada con [esta otra](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/1650/qu%C3%A9-son-los-delegados-en-c) pero ya nos dirás